# How to avoid texture distortion (namely have a higher resolution textures)

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures

I am bothered with the texture quality.I loaded a Obj file to display 3-D model, and used a 2048 * 2048 2-D image for 3-D model's texture mapping in android using Opengl-ES. The model with texture can be optionally rotated and zoomed, but when magnifying it to a certain ratio, the texture began to distortion.

I am wondering how to avoid the distortion during the amplification, which is similar to Google earth.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can change the object texture based on the distance between the camera and the object. so can use more detailed texture when the object is close ( that how Google earth work).

Comment: Thank you for your reply,How to switch the texture and get the time of switching the texture,which is shown low quality when scale in a certain ratio?

Comment: The question is how to judge the degree that will cause texture distortion when magnifying the 3D model (that is how to achieve the magnification ratio from the high-resolution texture to the mosaic effect)

Comment: what i described here is a technique called "level of detail", which is basically switching to a lower (or higher) quality mesh/texture/shader based on the distance of the model from the eye/camera. so the distance in which you need to change the texture is up to you.

Comment: How to implement the LOD algorithm? have you some code about it in android or opengl es? thanks!

Comment: you can view the link [texture mapping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006227/on-android-2-3-how-can-i-ensure-not-to-compromise-the-definition-of-its-texture)