# On Android 2.3, how can I ensure not to compromise the definition of its texture while enlarging a 3D object?

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, scale

Now I'm developing an Android-based 3D app with opengl-es 2.0, I made use of an OBJ file which consists of a 3D model and a texture image (like below):

[image]

Currently, the apple can rotate freely on my Samsung Galaxy II with no problem. Next, I want to enlarge the apple while keeping the definition of its texture, but I didn't make it (see below). I need help to achieve that. Any suggestion or pointing would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with the second picture?

Comment: It's shown low-quality texture and fuzzy.

Comment: Are you just concerned that your source texture is not of sufficient resolution to make it look "interesting" at that level of zoom? Either you need to start with higher resolution textures or write code to progressively blend in a detail texture (such as that described here http://udn.epicgames.com/Two/DetailTexture.html)

Comment: Thank you for your comment,I tried to start with higher resolution textures by opengl-es,but failed in technology.can you share any code about the detail texture?

Comment: @Ernest.Huang Maybe this is a silly question but, as an easier alternative to detail textures, did you try using texture compression? I expect ETC1 should work reasonably well with that texture.   Failing that, I don't have any example code for "detail textures" but it's a relatively simple concept; you just need an extra texture layer, with a much higher rate of repetition than the base texture and preferably not aligned with it, that is used to 'modulate' the base texture. It'd probably help have the lower res MIP map levels transparent so that it doesn't have an effect when zoomed out.